# how could I open a url in a third party browser not the default one?

Tags: javascript, url

I have an app running in android cell phone, I have set firefox as the default browser. When I open a url (like "www.mysql.com") from the app, it's not in the default browser(firefox), but in the cell phone's own, I don't want this. I want to open it in the default one, how should I do?

Comment: Why not set firefox as the default browser?

Comment: Is this a site/page hosted on a public web server, or is it a local project only (hosted on IIS or filesystem using file protocol).

Answer (score 3):

**That is not possible for security reasons.**

Imagine a situation where this is possible and browser allows to open another browser which is typically an application in your machine and some hacker create a link clicking on which may invoke an application or multiple applications, It would cause many many problems.